# @@ROWCOUNT shows as 0 when deleting using dynamic query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing a trouble when using dynamic query and when trying to get the number of deleted records using @@ROWCOUNT

Here is my QUery

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)='delete from '+ @table_name + ' where kfh_id=' + cast(@kfh_id as varchar)
--print @query
exec (@query)
print @query
insert into tbl_cleanup_log (tablename,kfh_id,rows_affected,remark,deletiontime)
values(@table_name,@kfh_id,@@ROWCOUNT,@query,getdate())
```

Here after the dyanimic delete query (inside my cursor) I am trying to store the number of deleted records into another table using @@ROWCOUNT. But it shows as 0.

I didnt understand what I did wrong.

My SQL version is 2012

Comment: `0` is right, `print @query` returns `0` rows.

Comment: On a different note, it's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to. You should most certainly be using a parametrised call to `sys.sp_executesql`; your code is open to injection attacks.

Comment: @Larnu We are using this query block just for a cleanup purpose. Neither saving it as an SP nor using in code

Comment: @Larnu Thats an eye opener bro. I missed I did a print statement there.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please don't use gender-specific terms like `bro`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Got you.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@@ROWCOUNT` is working correctly. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. If the number of rows is more than 2 billion, use ROWCOUNT_BIG.

The prior statement to the statement you use `@@ROWCOUNT` in is `print @query` and that returns no rows, and hence `@@ROWCOUNT` returns `0`.

To fix this I would suggest `PRINT`ing your dynamic statement first. Also you need to fix your dynamic statement so it isn't open to injection. Don't use the syntax `EXEC (@SQL)`, use a parametrised call to `sys.sp_executesql` and ensure you properly delimit identify your dynamic object with `QUOTENAME`:

```sql
DECLARE @table_name sysname,
        @kfh_id int; --Guessed data type
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX) = N'delete from dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name) + N' where kfh_id= @kfh_id;'; --Schema is guessed.

PRINT @query;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query, N'@kfh_id int', @kfh_id; --Reminder, guessed @kfh_id data type

INSERT INTO tbl_cleanup_log (tablename,
                             kfh_id,
                             rows_affected,
                             remark,
                             deletiontime)
VALUES (@table_name, @kfh_id, @@ROWCOUNT, @query, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 2):

@@ROWCOUNT should be the used immediately after statement, here the PRINT is between and it's changing the result:

```
DECLARE @row_cnt INT;
EXEC (@query);
SET @row_cnt = @@ROWCOUNT;

print @query;
insert into tbl_cleanup_log (tablename,kfh_id,rows_affected,remark,deletiontime)
values(@table_name,@kfh_id,@row_cnt ,@query,getdate());
```